# Can I trust Java 8 update messages with mixed English/Chinese and those in all English equally well?

Tags: java, updates

Java update messages on my computer have recently (~month(s)) started appearing partly in Chinese,  meaning that I can't read part of the message or what looks like a link.

I also get them completely in English.

Should I be suspicious of the messages that come in mixed languages but not the ones that are all in English? Can I trust them both, and equally?

May 16, 2021 with mixed languages:

[image: A new version of Java is available message partly in Chinese]

May 23, 2021 all in English:

[image: A new version of Java is available message all in English]

---

I have an old version of macOS (10.11, yes I know, I'll retire this one soon) running on a 2012 laptop. I don't remember for sure why I have Java but I'm pretty sure that it's for running [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/).

I'm located where traditional Chinese characters are used so it's not surprising that there could be some in a message, but what surprises me is that this seems to have only started happening a month or two ago, and well...

Comment: I don't see a tag for mixed languages (i.e. "I can't read it but may need to respond" type questions) so any help with tagging is appreciated. Different but related Q about mixed language problems w/ macOS: [Are there any settings on my laptop that will tell my browser “I speak English”?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/325593/143729) and [Is region-specific blocking built-in to MacOS more extensive than a few emoji?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/328950/143729) and (slightly) [I live in Taipei, how can I get help by chat in English?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/365995/143729)

Comment: I don't really see a security question here. This seems just like a question about using a particular program/updater.

Comment: @multithr3at3d No, the question describes the *sudden change of languages in  certain parts* of the message which suggests the message may not be valid; may be coming from an unauthorized source. That concern didn't meet some threshold? Or did it not come through clearly?

Comment: I've **updated the question** since receiving a second message and I've explained more clearly that I'm concerned about the security issues here. Would Security SE be a better home now (was asked there originally, then migrated here)

Comment: I woudnt trust it.  If it IS legit, let Java fix it before trusting it.  That would make me not trust it.  WHY ANYWAYS?  What exactly am I updating?

Comment: Whether this fits on Security would be a question that is better asked on their meta site https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/. In order to "migrate it back" we would simply close the question here and the mods on [Security.se] would reopen the original rather than playing migration ping-pong.

Comment: @Mokubai okay I'll look into asking a question there in meta, *thanks!*